# User defined signal 1 terminates my POSIX program!

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

I have a program that runs some pthreads, and in every thread there is a `connect()`, `recv()` and `send()`. The problem is that sometimes it suddendly closes the entire program showing the message `"User defined signal 1"`. It runs in linux, using POSIX threads, in C. The code is like that:

```
pthread_mutex_t cur_lock;
int stop = 0;

 void SocketsFunction(){
 //..
connect();
while(recv()<0)
{
  //do stuff
send();
}
close();
return NULL;
}

void job()
{
 //..
while (!stop)
{
    if (something)
               //..
    else
    {
        stop = 1;
        break;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cur_lock);

    SocketsFunction();

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cur_lock);
}

pthread_mutex_unlock(&cur_lock);

return NULL;
}

main(){
//..
 pthread_mutex_init(&cur_lock, NULL);
//..
 for(i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    pthread_create(&pID, NULL, job, NULL);

 //..
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something is sending "User defined signal 1" (`SIGUSR1` I believe) to your process, and the default action for this signal is to terminate the process. If you want to avoid that you need to either stop whatever is sending the signal, install a signal handler for the signal, or block the signal in all threads (e.g. at the beginning of main before creating any threads) with `pthread_sigmask`.

Since the code you included in your question has nothing to do with signal handling or what's sending the signal, I can't really be more specific.

Comment: So,your idea is that we will init pthread_sigmask in main function when running program.